Post notices for closed and locked contradict each other
This question is both closed and locked.
The close notice says the question is not currently accepting answers.
The locked notice states that comments have been disabled, but that it is accepting answers.

A question cannot be both accepting new answers and not accepting new answers.  The lock notice is newer than the close notice, but the text of the lock notice is incorrect.

Yeah, the lock message is only talking about the effect of the lock. It doesn't consider that it may have been applied to a closed question. An improvement would be:

Comments on this question have been disabled, but it is still accepting new answers (unless it has been closed) and other interactions.

This change might need to be made Stack Exchange wide, rather than uniquely at Law.SE.

Probably it's SE wide; I happened to not notice it before.

@gerrit this is SE-wide and unique to comment-lock reason. Other lock reasons prevent new answers. (Ref: What are these notices above my post?)
